# How to refresh app (activity) while it's still running?

Tags: java, android, xml

I just made an app that asks an addition question. I want to refresh the whole app, how do I do that? All I need to know is how to refresh it - the questions, rest I can figure out by myself.

What I'm aiming for is just for the screen to go back to the beginning screen, not the app closes itself and then restart.(If that's the only way whatever, it's useable)

java:

```
package com.example.android.mathapp;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
private boolean correct;
private String questionTxt, option1String, option2String, option3String, option4String;
private int answer;
TextView option1Text, option2Text, option3Text, option4Text;
private String[] ansString = new String[4];
private int counter = 0;
float f = 100;

public void correctAnswer()
{
    int first = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    int second = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
    answer = first + second;
    questionTxt = first + " + " + second + " = ?";
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);

    /*ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);
    rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.greencartooncar);
    rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();*/

    TextView questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
    correctAnswer();
    questionText.setText(questionTxt + "");
    TextView directionsEnd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.directions);
    directionsEnd.setText("Get 10 questions right to finish the race!");
    makeOptions(answer);
    option1Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option1);
    option1Text.setText(ansString[0]);
    option2Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option2);
    option2Text.setText(ansString[1]);
    option3Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option3);
    option3Text.setText(ansString[2]);
    option4Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option4);
    option4Text.setText(ansString[3]);
    setString();
    //noSameAnswer();
}

private String[] makeOptions(int correctAns) {

    for(int i=0;i<ansString.length;i++)
    {
        ansString[i] = null;
    }

    int randomPos = (new Random().nextInt(4 - 1) + 1);
    ansString[randomPos]=correctAns + "";

    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
        int randomAns = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + Math.random() * 10);
        if(ansString[i] == null){
            ansString[i]=randomAns + "";
        }
    }

    if (ansString[0].equals(ansString[1])||ansString[0].equals(ansString[2])||ansString[0].equals(ansString[3])
            ||ansString[1].equals(ansString[2]) ||ansString[1].equals(ansString[3])||ansString[2].equals(ansString[3]))
    {
        makeOptions(answer);
    }

    return ansString;
}

/*public void noSameAnswer()
{
    if (option1String.equals(option2String)||option1String.equals(option3String)||option1String.equals(option4String)
            ||option2String.equals(option3String)||option2String.equals(option4String)||option3String.equals(option4String))
    {
        makeOptions(answer);
        option1Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option1Text.setText(ansString[0]);
        option2Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option2Text.setText(ansString[1]);
        option3Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option3Text.setText(ansString[2]);
        option4Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option4);
        option4Text.setText(ansString[3]);
        setString();
        noSameAnswer();
    }
}*/

public void onClick3(View v) {
    if (option3String.equals(Integer.toString(answer))) {
        counter++;
        TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        correctAnswer();
        questionText.setText(questionTxt + "");
        makeOptions(answer);
        option1Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option1Text.setText(ansString[0]);
        option2Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option2Text.setText(ansString[1]);
        option3Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option3Text.setText(ansString[2]);
        option4Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option4);
        option4Text.setText(ansString[3]);
        setString();
        animate();
        //noSameAnswer();
    }
}

public void onClick1(View v) {
    if (option1String.equals(Integer.toString(answer))) {
        counter++;
        TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        correctAnswer();
        questionText.setText(questionTxt + "");
        makeOptions(answer);
        option1Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option1Text.setText(ansString[0]);
        option2Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option2Text.setText(ansString[1]);
        option3Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option3Text.setText(ansString[2]);
        option4Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option4);
        option4Text.setText(ansString[3]);
        setString();
        animate();
        //noSameAnswer();
    }
}

public void onClick2(View v) {
    if (option2String.equals(Integer.toString(answer))) {
        counter++;
        TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        correctAnswer();
        questionText.setText(questionTxt + "");
        makeOptions(answer);
        option1Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option1Text.setText(ansString[0]);
        option2Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option2Text.setText(ansString[1]);
        option3Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option3Text.setText(ansString[2]);
        option4Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option4);
        option4Text.setText(ansString[3]);
        setString();
        animate();
        //noSameAnswer();
    }
}

public void onClick4(View v) {
    if (option4String.equals(Integer.toString(answer))) {
        counter++;
        TextView questionText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        correctAnswer();
        questionText.setText(questionTxt + "");
        makeOptions(answer);
        option1Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option1);
        option1Text.setText(ansString[0]);
        option2Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option2);
        option2Text.setText(ansString[1]);
        option3Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option3);
        option3Text.setText(ansString[2]);
        option4Text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.option4);
        option4Text.setText(ansString[3]);
        setString();
        animate();
        //noSameAnswer();
    }
}

public void setString()
{
    option1String = option1Text.getText().toString();
    option2String = option2Text.getText().toString();
    option3String = option3Text.getText().toString();
    option4String = option4Text.getText().toString();
}

public void animate()
{
    ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.car);

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(f - 100, f,
            0.0f, 0.0f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    img_animation.startAnimation(animation);
    f += 100;
}
}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/bigboi"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.mathapp.MainActivity">
```

-->

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option3"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background = "@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:onClick="onClick3"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:text="option 3" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option1"
    android:text="option 1"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background = "@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:layout_above="@+id/option3"
    android:onClick="onClick1"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option2"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background = "@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="option 2"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:layout_above="@+id/option3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option3"
    android:onClick="onClick2"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/car"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/greencartooncar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/option4"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background = "@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="option 4"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/option3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/option3"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:onClick="onClick4"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/question"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/option1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/directions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@id/question"
    android:textSize="15sp"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/finish"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/finish"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/directions"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="FINISH"
    android:layout_below="@+id/finish"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/finish"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/finish" />
```

Comment: you mean refresh, right? Also, add your code.

Comment: Can we see your code so we know what needs to be reset on the 'restart'?

Comment: @Nilesh Singh  without authors approval but the reviewers , i think you are doing a damage to the original post by adding your own words to edit it and get it approved  because answers can be different depends on those words.If he wants to refresh then he do Not want to **go back to the Beginning screen**

Comment: I just want the app to go back to the beginning once you hit 10 questions

Comment: I'll add the code, its lengthy

Comment: btw I mean the whole app refreshes, not just the questions since I want the animation to start at the beginning too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
        Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(YourCurrActivity.this, ClassYouNeedToReLaunch.class);
        int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(YourCurrActivity.this, mPendingIntentId,    mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)YourCurrActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
```

If you want to call it in different activities create a static method,

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Util {

    static void reStartActivity(Context currant, Class needToLoad ){
        Intent mStartActivity = new Intent(currant,needToLoad);
        int mPendingIntentId = 123456;
        PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(currant, mPendingIntentId,mStartActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)currant.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        mgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 100, mPendingIntent);
    }
}
```

and call it in any class, `Util.reStartActivity(YourCurrActivity.this,ClassYouNeedToReLaunch.class);`

may be that's your problem.

or

If you have a `splashActivity` or something similler Just call that activity again using normal `Intent`.

Comment: So if I use the first code segment and put it in a method, once the method is called the app will refresh like it was just run?

Comment: @Larry Jing its `WhatEverYourActivityName.this` . I accidentally put it as Test.this ill change it